# Convert ascii to char

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, ascii

I try to convert "sum" into char but when i display out "charList" it is still ascii.

```
for (int i = 0; i < final.size() /8 ; i++)

        {
            for (int ii = A ;   ii < B; ii++)
            {
                sum = sum + multi * final.at(ii);
                multi = multi * 2;
            }

            char charVar = (char)sum;

            charList.push_back(charVar);

            cout << sum << endl;

            if(multi > 128)
            {
                multi = 1;
                sum = 0;
            }


            A = A + 8;
            B = A + 8;
        }


        copy(charList.begin(), charList.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

Is there any other simple way to convert it to char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing `int`s to stdout.  Try making your `std::vector` hold `char` instead of `int`.

Comment: my vector is something like this "vector<char> charList;" , is it correct?

Comment: @user3743939: That should be correct.  Try changing `int` to `char` in `ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")`.

Comment: my silly mistake, alright thanks it solved my problem.